# What's the best solution to implement this?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with project that will have ONLY one profile that has friends

I allready do that by

- static class profile
- class friend
- profile has static collection of friends

but profile and friend have same variables as name , pic , .. etc

so i decide to make a person abstract class and inherit it

then i found that i can't inherit static class [ profile ] from person as variables will not have properties

so i made variables as static in person

then every friend doesn't have its variables as static variables will belongs to friend class

I'm new to this and i know it's a silly question !!

but what's the best way to implement this

I Preferred Using Static For Profile For Accessibility

I Preferred Using Static Things For Accessibility Purposes

Comment: Presumably you are aware that a static variable means everyone shares the same value?  Perhaps you should just not use static at all and derive everything from a person class.

Comment: yes, friends not share same value but profile in only one  , I want to access profile from any other class so i preferred to implement it as static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using static classes. If you want one instance, just create one instance. Static classes make testing difficult.

But going back to design, maybe try introducing a User class:

```
class User
 - name
 - picture
 - other properties

class Profile
 - User myAccountInfo
 - List<User> friends
```

Comment: friend may have variables that are NOT in user !!

Comment: I want to access profile from any other class so i preferred to implement it as static

Comment: @Ahmed Adel it sounds like you are trying to do procedural programing instead of OOP... don't do this.  Instead make it a member variable and have other objects access it through an instance of the Profile class.

Comment: @Yaur I never feel difference between procedural programing & OOP =(

Comment: so I made your one but with some change  i made class user and made a static class profile with have static variable user  ,, but the problem now that i was accessing profile.name from xaml like that {Binding Source={x:Static local:Profile.Name}} NOW how i will access Profile.Data.Name ????

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?:

```
class User
{
    public User(string name, object picture)
    {
        Name = name;
        Picture = picture;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Picture { get; set; } //Change object to a class that holds Picture information.
}

class Profile : User
{
    private static Profile _profile;

    public List<User> Friends = new List<User>(); //This List<T> can contain instances of (classes that derive from) User.

    public Profile(string name, object picture) : base(name, picture) { }
    public static Profile GetProfile()
    {
        return _profile ?? (_profile = new Profile("NameOfProfileHere", null));
    }
}
```